# Decrease element size by a factor then increase by same factor to original size

Tags: javascript, rounding

First of all, I know the root of my problem here is rounding in Javascript, I just don't know how to mitigate for it in this particular instance.

I have an element which I want to allow the user to decrease in height by clicking a 'zoom out' button. The decrease in height will be as a proportion of the element's current height - for example, if the element is 100px high, zooming out with the zoom factor set to 0.3 once would reduce its height to 70px. Zooming out again would reduce its height to 49px, and so on.

There is also a 'zoom in' button on the page. After zooming out, the user should be able to use the 'zoom in' button to increase the element's height again. Critically, each increment of the element's height on zooming back in should match the increments seen when zooming out. For example, if the element's heights on zooming out were: 100, 70, 49, 34.3, 24.01 then when zooming back in again, the element's heights would be 24.01, 34.3, 49, 70 100.

I've created a fiddle demonstrating this functionality [here](https://jsfiddle.net/philipstratford/ug710caz/). You'll notice that if you run it and initially click the 'zoom out' button (labelled '-') seven times in a row, then click the 'zoom in' button seven times in a row, rather than returning the element's height to 100px, it ends up as 95.7142...px, and the other heights on zooming in don't match those on zooming out either.

```
$(function() {
  var zoomAmount = 0.3;
  var $el = $("#testDiv");

  $("#zoomIn").click(function() {
    var currentHeight = $el.height();
    var newHeight = currentHeight * (1 / (1 - zoomAmount));
    //newHeight = Math.round(newHeight * 10000 / 10000);
    $el.height(newHeight);
    $el.html(newHeight);
    if (newHeight >= 100) {
        $("#zoomIn").prop("disabled", true);
    }
  });

  $("#zoomOut").click(function() {
    $("#zoomIn").prop("disabled", false);
    var currentHeight = $el.height();
    var newHeight = currentHeight * (1 - zoomAmount);
    //newHeight = Math.round(newHeight * 10000 / 10000);
    $el.height(newHeight);
    $el.html(newHeight);
  });
});
```

I understand that this is caused by an accumulation of rounding in the calculation used to zoom out and then back in, but I don't know how to avoid it. You can see that I've commented out a couple of lines which were attempting to round the element's height to 2 decimal places each time, but they don't help. With them uncommented, the element's height ends up as 96px, which suggests to me that even though I'm rounding to 2dp before setting the value as the element's height, it's still aware of the full, unrounded number somehow and is using it when calculating the next new height.

The only solution I can think of is to store the values of the element's height in an array as I zoom in and out, so that when I zoom in the opposite direction the new height is looked up from the array rather than re-calculated, but that doesn't feel very elegant. Additionally, in my actual application there are dozens of the elements on page at a time, each with a different height, so I'd have to track the height of each one in its own array, which seems even less elegant.

Is there a way to calculate the height of the element as I zoom out and in (in practice you could zoom in then out too, but that requires more code so I simplified it) which will ensure that at each 'zoom increment' the height of the element is always the same?

Comment: Storing the various zoom sizes in an array sounds like a great idea to me.

Comment: Storing the values is the only reliable option in this case.

Comment: If you keep the original size value, keep the modifier separately and calculate the end value from does two, you won't have any rounding issue when increasing and decreasing the modifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an exponential function, and keep your  zoomAmount  as an integer (a better name would then be something like `zoomLevel`). So, instead of modifying a  float  which will accumulate rounding error, you can simply do `zoomAmount++` or  `zoomAmount--`  , and then get the real scale of your elements by elevating a floating-point number to `zoomAmount` (typically the numbere, you can then adjust your graphics with some constants as you see fit).
For example:

```
$el.height = base_height * pow(2.7182, zoomAmount)
```

Make sure you start with `zoomAmount = 0`, since e^0 = 1.
As no rounding errors exist with integers, you are guaranteed to have consistent zoom levels. Another advantage of this solution is that it has a low memory footprint, since you only need to save a single base height for every element of your document.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of elegant solution I was looking for. I've updated my fiddle for anybody who wants to see it in action (I hope I understood your explanation - it works so it seems that way!). https://jsfiddle.net/philipstratford/ug710caz/44/

Answer (score 0):

You could store the previous values and pop back on zoom in ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ug710caz/17/)).

```
$(function() {
    var values = [];

    $("#zoomIn").click(function() {
        var newHeight = values.pop();
        // ...
    });

    $("#zoomOut").click(function() {
        var currentHeight = $el.height(); // this value gets stored
        values.push(currentHeight);
        // ...
    });
});
```

Comment: Actually, did you notice that if you zoom in with this, you get 23.79999999997 on the zoom IN, but 24 on the zoom out?

Comment: @Snowmonkey, it takes the height form the object `var currentHeight = $el.height();`, not the computed value.

Comment: Yup, I see that -- you can't necessarily set the height to 24.3px, for example. When you do, and then read it back, it'll be an integer.